# Arrays in session jsp

Tags: arrays, jsp, session, casting

i want to create session for shopping cart, I need to put an array to a session, but I always have an error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList.

Here's my shopping cart array variable :

`ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) session.getAttribute("cart");`

Comment: The error says you are trying to cast int into arraylist. Are you sure the attribute "cart" is type of array list? Can you share the code where you set cart attribute to session?

Comment: You seem to have a problem with types :). What you have stored in this session attribute is an Integer, not an ArrayList. And an ArrayList and an array are not the same type either. Search for the place where you add the cart to the session.

Comment: full code : ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) session.getAttribute("cart");  
   if(list == null)
   {
    
   }
   else
   {
    Integer num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    list.add(num);
   Integer kiekis2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kiekis"));
    list.add(kiekis2); 
    session.setAttribute("cart", list);
   }